# Got an error , during calling an WCF service through windows application

Tags: windows

The binding at system.serviceModel/bindings/webHttpBinding does not have a configured binding named 'webBinding'. This is an invalid value for bindingConfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem with your config, possibly you are trying to use `webHttpBinding` but didn't define any `bindingConfiguration` named `webBinding` in the `bindings` section.

something like -

```
<webHttpBinding>
   <binding name="webBinding">          
   </binding>
</webHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Thank you amit, i had given the diffrent name to the bindingConfiguration . But it resolve by giving the bindingConfiguration is equal to binding name.  <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP"       ------------- <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP"
                  contract="wcfrestserviceCalling.IService1"
                  behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"/>